# App Clips - lazy loading image via network to reduce size

Tags: ios, apple-appclips

I have a question regarding the size of AppClips. On apple documentation they writing the following about the size:

> **Keep Your App Clip Small in Size**
>
> App Clips must be small — no more than 10 MB for the uncompressed App
> Clip — to launch instantly. If possible, keep your App Clip well below
> this limit.
>
> To measure your App Clip’s size, create an app-size report for your
> App Clip:
>
> In Xcode, archive the App Clip’s corresponding app, open the Organizer
> window, select the archive, and click Distribute App.
>
> Export the App Clip as an Ad Hoc or Development build with App
> Thinning and Rebuild from Bitcode enabled.
>
> The output folder for your exported App Clip contains its size report:
> a file named App Thinning Size Report.txt. Open the text file, note
> your App Clip’s uncompressed size for each variant, and then make
> adjustments to your project to keep the uncompressed size for each
> variant below 10 MB.

Does anyone know if its allowed to lazy load image via the network to reduce the size of assets, because in my current app clip they take pretty much half of the size. So to say, has anyone tried to upload an app clip which is doing that without getting rejected?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Reserve the following functionality for the full app: On-demand resources

Answer (score 1):

We have created an app clip and were using AWS3 however it was using to much space (the library) we are now loading the images similar to this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTcQnf6ziew

It is a video about loading images by network and storing them in NSCache, great tutorial the the results are very clean.

You will have to store your images in a public repository that you are able to access via URL - then store those url's somewhere (db or local) for you project to access them.

If using a public image folder be sure to restrict write access.

EXAMPLE:

```
import UIKit


var imageCahe = NSCache<AnyObject,AnyObject>()
extension UIImageView {





func load(urlString:String){
    
    
    if let image = imageCahe.object(forKey: urlString as NSString){
        self.image = image as? UIImage
        return
    }
    
    guard let url = URL(string:urlString)else{
        return
    }
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
        
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
            if let image = UIImage(data: data){
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    imageCahe.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    self?.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

You can then call this method by using a UIImageView.

```
x = Your ImageView 

x.load(url:"https://image.com")
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. It would be good if you could add some more technical explanations or relevant code snippets to your answer to explain what is being done. The video might do a good job for this, but in case it is e.g. taken down this would reduce the value of your answer as nobody can follow in more detail what you did.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) against loading assets via the network for an App Clip, so you're good. I think they even suggest this technique in one of the WWDC videos about App Clips.

If you haven't already, you can also look into embedding vector images/PDFs and using things like PNGCrush to decrease the size of your assets.